# Is there a way to active a .cs function and a javascript function with the same button ( both onclick)?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

**Problem**

I want to create a modal "Forgot Password" , in this modal there is a button "send code" and when you click on that button it should activate the .cs function (in this function it will create a random code and will mail the code to the user) and the button "Send code" should also activate the javascript function  ( this function will close the current modal and go to the next modal)  at the same time.

**What I already tried**

I tried:
To  put the in the same onclick event ,
Put the cs function onserver click and the JS function onclick 
Tried an a tag button 
and an input button

**Button**

```
<asp:Button ID="SendCode" Text="Send code" runat="server" OnClick="VerzendCode;b();" CssClass="btn btn-default" Visible="true" />
```

**CS function**

```
public partial class Site1 : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{ protected void VerzendCode(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string code = generateCode();
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("demert.deswert@gmail.com", TxtEmailWW.Text);
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("demert.deswert@gmail.com", "789632145");
        mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
        mail.Subject = "Wachtwoord vergeten";
        mail.Body = "Beste  dit is de code om uw wachtwoord te resetten";
        mail.Body += Environment.NewLine + code;
        client.Send(mail);  
    }
 }
```

**JS function**

```
$(function b() {
    $("#BtnVerzendcode").click(function () {
        $('#WWReset').modal('show');
          $('#WWvergeten').modal('hide');
    });
});
```

**Expection**

I expect that both functions active at the sime time and with the same button

Comment: the .cs code runs *on the server* while the JS code runs *on the client*. It's literally impossible for them to run at the same time. They don't even run in the same place, after all.

Comment: Why wouldn't you create a controller to handle an event to send an email?

Comment: VLAZ unless you use WebForms. It's possible to have the attribute JavaScript run as well as the .cs code. I would NOT recommend this. There's a reason people don't use it anymore

Comment: You can create a hidden asp:button that is clicked through the JS. E.g.
$('#yourHiddenAspButton').trigger('click');

Comment: @Bedir could you give some more information about that hidden asp:button please? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use AJAX which stands for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML. Here is an example of what you might need:

```
    $(function b() {
        $("#BtnVerzendcode").click(function () {
            $('#WWReset').modal('show');
              $('#WWvergeten').modal('hide');
              var url = "@Url.Action("VerzendCode","Site1")";
              var dataToSend = { };
              $.ajax({
                  url: url,
                  type:'GET',
                  success: function(result){
                  $('#WWReset').text(result);
             }
           });
        });
    });
```

This will send an asynchronous request to your controller action therefore the javascript and C# function will basically run at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the help , but is there a different way to do it? I'm not a experienced web developer , and i'm having some problems with AJAX , not a big fan on of it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So the point is to run front end logic, and then within the JavaScript call the back end logic.

HTML

```
<asp:Button ID="SendCode" runat="server" Visible="false" disabled OnClick="VerzendCode"/>
<button id="sendCodeBtn" class="btn btn-default" onclick="b();">Send Code</button>
```

JS/JQuery:

```
function b(){
    $('#sendCodeBtn').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $('#SendCode').prop('disabled', false);
    setTimeout(function () {//timeout is to help avoid double click
        $('#SendCode').trigger('click');
    }, 500);
}
```

C#

```
protected void VerzendCode(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to fix it , but this solution does not call the C# code  "VerzendCode". Any ideas why? I also assume disabled should be disabled ="True".

Comment: The hidden asp button calls VerzendCode once function b() triggers a click of that hidden button.